# How can I Access Global Variables from inside a Class Function

Tags: python, function, class

Based on all the examples I reviewed, this should work.

```
px = 0.5; py = 0.7;
class posPoint:
    print("test",px,",",py)

    def functTest():
        px = 0.1; py = 0.8
        print("inside function",px,",",py)

posPoint.functTest()
print("\toutside class",px,",",py)
```

However, the results are not what I want.

> ```
> inside function 0.1 , 0.8
> outside class 0.5 , 0.7
> ```

From [GeeksforGeeks](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-using-variable-outside-and-inside-the-class-and-method/)...
*Variable defined outside the class:
The variables that are defined outside the class can be accessed by any class or any methods in the class by just writing the variable name.*

I don't understand why the change in the function was not accessed.
Did I miss something?

Comment: By "accessed", they mean "looked at". You can't assign to outer variables that way.

Comment: Use `global` if you want to assign global variables.

Comment: This is the same for class methods as for ordinary functions.

Comment: That's odd. This example works.
# Variable defined outside the class.
outVar = 'outside_class'    
print("Outside_class1", outVar)
  
''' Class one '''
class Geek:
    print("Outside_class2", outVar)
  
    def access_method(self):
        print("Outside_class3", outVar)
Mine does not, but they are no different... at least as far as I can see.

Comment: I guess I have to use the global keyword then, on a number of already global variables. This would have been so much easier in c#, but I felt forced to use python, as I am working with QGIS.